# How to get Button's Value clicked from other activity

Tags: android

I have 4 activities (A,B,C,D) and Activities(A,B,C) has a button and Activity C is the WebView to display URL sent from A,B,C.

Example Button value in Activities (A,B,C):

```
Button A = http://www.google.com/
Button B = http://www.facebook.com/
Button C = http://www.linkedin.com/
```

So, when press on above button it will call Activity C to display URL from button that clicked.

Can you tell the sample how to that?

Best Regards,
Sopheap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

first you need to **implement on click listener** for your *class Activity*.

```
public class A extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

then set *listener to Buttons* you used.

```
Button a,b,c;
    a.setOnClickListener(this);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    c.setOnClickListener(this);
```

you use override **onClick()** method.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v == a){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), c.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", "http://www.google.com/");
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if(v == b){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), c.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", "http://www.facebook.com/");
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if(v == c){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), c.class);
        intent.putExtra("url", "http://www.twitter.com/");
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

get that value from **C.java** from following code.

```
String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
```

then you have your url in *String* **url** variable, and use this.

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling Activity D from Activity A , just pass the value stored in the button of activity A in the intent.
For example:

```
 Intent login = new Intent(A.this, D.class);
 Bundle lBundleData = new Bundle();
 lBundleData.putString("google.com", mUrlAddress);
 login.putExtras(lBundleData);
 startActivity(login);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, D.class);
intent.putExtra("url", ButtonA.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

In D onCreate

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```